# Python Datareader Stock Exchange markets options

Tags: python, pandas, datareader, stock

I'm using Datareader to get some stock quotes from Yahoo finance. I would like to get the values of Euronext Paris Stock exchange market and not the standard values (NYSE ones I think).

```
    import pandas.io.data as web
    import time
    today = time.strftime(\"%m/%d/%Y\")
    valeur = web.DataReader('ING.PA',data_source='yahoo',start='1/1/2000',end=today)
```

Is there an option in Datareader method to indicate I want Euronext closing values ?

I have seen in Yahoo Finance API that there is a tag x for Stock Exchange that can be useful to precise the market on which you want to get values (http://www.marketindex.com.au/yahoo-finance-api) but I can't see any example value I can pass to this x tag to try it. And I don't know if I can use an equivalent in Datareader afterwards.

I have also founnd a page describing google_exchange codes indicating the one I'm looking for ('EPA') but I don't how to transpose it in DataReader.
https://github.com/mdengler/stockquote/blob/master/stockquote.py

Does anyone as a clue on this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The suffix in the code `.PA` indicates the exchange you want to obtain, Paris in this case.

Take a look at [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all;_ylt=Ak0bQJEijLNpCehrNmNeE8LXVax_;_ylu=X3oDMTE4MnA1bzlpBHBvcwMxBHNlYwN5ZmlTeW1ib2xMb29rdXBSZXN1bHRzBHNsawNhbGw-?s=Ingenico&t=A&m=ALL&r=) to see the different symbols you can use according to the exchange you want to get data from. Then use the appropriate symbol in the call.

```
Symbol      Name            Last Trade  Type    Industry/Category   Exchange
ING.PA      Ingenico Group  101.45      Stock   Business Services   PAR
ING.SW      INGENICO GROUP  116.30      Stock                       EBS
IIE.F       INGENICO GROUP  100.90      Stock   Business Services   FRA
IIE.SG      INGENICO GROUP  102.88      Stock   Business Services   STU
INGIY       Ingenico Group  23.05       Stock                       PNK
INGNV.PA    Ingenico S.A.   98.33       Stock                       PAR
IIEF.EX     INGENICO GROUP  115.49      Stock                       EUX
IIE.BE      INGENICO GROUP  106.70      Stock   Business Services   BER
```

Here is a quote from the [Yahoo Finance API](http://www.marketindex.com.au/yahoo-finance-api) page.

> All listed companies have a stock ticker between 1 and 4 characters. E.g. Apple has the stock ticker AAPL. As there are multiple exchanges around the world, you must specify which exchange your code relates to by adding a suffix.
>
> - Australian listed companies require the suffix “.AX” to be added to the companies stock code (e.g. BHP.AX).
> - UK listed companies require the suffix “.L” to be added to the companies stock code (e.g. BLT.L).

Comment: I agree. The .PA suffix should get me the close value of Paris market. But I need to wait till midnight (Paris time) to get the close value of my company. I think it's the time the US market closes. I would like to know if I can get the close value as soon as the Paris market is closed.